# Access child in nested vector of unknown depth using vector of indexes

Tags: c++

My goal is to be able to have a vector of indexes and navigate to that in a class with a vector of variants of vectors and that class.

Say I have an "index vector" of unknown size with `{0, 4, 7, 2}` I would want to somehow use that to access `someVector[0][4][7][2]`.

someVector is of a class node
defined as:

```
class node
{
  public:
    node operator[](unsigned int index)
    {
      return std::get<node>(children[index]);
    }

  private:
    std::vector<std::variant<node, std::string>> children;
}
```

I had the idea of using a loop and a reference but couldn't figure that out.
My idea was something along the lines of

```
node elementRef = &nodeObject;
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
{
  tempElementRef = &elementRef[indexVector[I]];
  elementRef = tempElementRef;
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `someVector` ? What if for the same `someVector` an "index vector" of size 3 is used? You want the subvector then?

Comment: A class with a vector of variants of a string and itself. I edited my original post to for more detail.

Comment: wouldn't be easier if you use an std::map for the indexes

Comment: Also, why does `operator[]` return a `node` rather than a `node&`?  I'm lost as to what is supposed to happen if the particular child contains a string rather than a node.  There must be exceptions to handle when trying to follow a path through the graph that results in a string-edge rather than a node-edge

Comment: I have both node operator[](unsigned int index) and const node &node operator[](...) const. I read somewhere that that's the correct way

Comment: Not sure I get what the problem is. If you want to assign to the reference, not to object it points to, use [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C++20 you can do it like this:

```cpp
node accessNode(node n, std::span<unsigned int> span)
{
    return span.size() ? accessNode(n[span[0]], span.subspan(1)) : n;
}
```

example usage:

```cpp
std::vector<unsigned int> coordinates = {0, 4, 7, 2};
accessNode(someNode, coordinates);
```

**note:** Handling exceptions from bad indices or children that are not nodes is left up to you.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.